# Programmatically send SMS msgs using your personal mobile account?

Tags: sms, mobile-phones, sms-gateway

Is it possible to programmatically send SMS msgs using your personal mobile account?

Are there any mobile networks (location unimportant for now) that allow a subscriber to send sms via a gateway api?

Comment: I think location does matter.

Comment: On what platform are you working? Android? iPhone? Other?

Comment: @klez I just want to see if there's examples first.

@fredley - I'm looking for something platform agnostic - ie an open endpoint that can be connected to over a network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Short message peer-to-peer protocol (SMPP) that mobile operators uses for that purpose. It is running over TCP/IP network. Sometimes the connection point is accessible through Internet, sometimes you have to connect to their private network.

Of course, you have to have some kind of agreement with the telecom company.

I hope this can serve you as a staring point , I'm aware that I didn't help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a smart phone you could probably download a sms gateway app. for android for example you can use [SMS Gateway ME](http://smsgateway.me) ([Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=networked.solutions.sms.gateway.api)) which let you send and receive SMS messages from your phone over HTTP.

Comment: I don't thing the OP meant sending using an App